# Dropping process rights under windows

Tags: security, winapi, setuid

I'm looking for a method to drop process rights for security reasons. I want to start as user with privileges and end as limited user.

For example I want my web server to run under restricted user by I still want to listen on port 80.

How can I do such things under Windows. Something similar to Unix's:

```
bind_to_80();
chroot("/some/limited/dir");
setuid(limited_user_id);
setgid(limited_group_id);
chroot("/some/limited/dir");
// drop some more rights
fork(); // now I can't come back
```

How can I do something similar under Windows?

Edit: Of course I understand that Windows does not have fork or chroot, but I'm looking for dropping various rights, especially user - best practices.

Comment: Did you try just running as the unprivileged user?  I am setting up a rest api server under windows for the first time.  I used the service management console to configure the service to run as a non-admin user.  It still binds and listens on port 80 with no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Mark Russinovich's description](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2006/03/02/running-as-limited-user-the-easy-way.aspx) of stripping privileges under Windows using [`CreateRestrictedToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446583%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`CreateProcessAsUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682429%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). As he explains, this isn't bulletproof since the account under which the process is running still retains its privileges.

And of course, his [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) sysinternals utility helps you strip away at least `Administrator` privileges, without requiring coding.

For an existing process, it seems [`AdjustToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375202%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`AdjustTokenGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) permit manipulation (the former apparently requires XPSP2 or higher), but require privileges themselves... it might be possible to commit privilege seppuku this way, but I haven't tried them: they **might** barf on manipulating privileges of the current process.

Comment: Is there possible to do it without starting other process?

Comment: I was wrong: some manipulation is possible. Edited to add. Not sure about reflective use on the running process. There's no substitute for trying!

Comment: Updated link to Russinvich's blog post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/running-as-limited-user-the-easy-way/ba-p/723506
May not be *entirely* up to date!