# How to achieve temporary admin rights windows for a windows service when starting up

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security

This question is closed [ [Dropping process rights under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966536/dropping-process-rights-under-windows) ] but it's very old, and the solution wasn't an exact match. I'm hoping to find a contemporary answer, and one that might work directly with C# with the BCLs of .Net Framework.

I have software that runs as a windows service, and it needs admin rights at startup but it doesn't need those rights for the remaining lifetime of the service.

In the ongoing pursuit of good security, I just feel that this is a feature that a OS should provide to user-level software. Downgrading security should be supported, so that software can operate with the lowest rights and reduce the potential for security issues.

Of course, as a console application, a second process can be spawned without administrator rights, but for a service, I might need to have two services.

I'm hoping there's a way within a single operating process, if not now, perhaps in the future

Comment: No you cant do this afaik, however you can impersonate accounts.

Comment: Why does it need rights only on startup?   Is it doing some kind of configuration or something that could possible be handled by an installer?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter In my case, it is downloading a configuration file, which results in system changes, but it might also update itself (program). For reference, it does have an installer too, for installation-time tasks. If there isn't a direct solution, I will probably need to have two services in the solution instead.

Comment: While workarounds are interesting, and technically an answer to the question "Can ...". I hope to learn more from others in the (near) future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not possible to accomplish within a single process in Windows today, the two-services approach is probably the best fallback option to accomplish what you need.

**Options**

1. **Downgrading** an individual Windows process - not possible today
2. **AppDomain sandboxing** - not perfect, because you still have a master app domain running with elevated rights. The elevated rights are not extinguished.
3. **Two Services** - the best option so far
4. **Other sandboxing** - beyond AppDomain sandboxing, other sandboxing solutions might exist, but they all likely have the same pros/cons - they still have a master domain running within the single process with elevated privileges.

---

**Two Services**

Here's how it would work as a workaround with two services.

The setup of two services:

- **Service 1** - The startup mode. Runs upon startup of Windows. Has System rights. Does what it needs to do, then starts `Service 2`, then stops itself.
- **Service 2** - The ongoing mode. Is started by `Service 1`, and has very restricted rights (possibly Network Service).

Both services can be installed with an MSI once.

**Background**

There are two ways to have two modes of operation for the total solution -  startup, and ongoing:

1. One program could run in two modes with different command-line arguments; or
2. There could be two separate EXE programs.

Also, the `startup` program might need to send state information to the `ongoing` one, and there are multiple ways to do this (It could be via memory IPC channel, localhost TCP, etc..). https://capnproto.org/ is a good option for IPC channel communication.

---

**AppDomains**

You can use AppDomains to create a sandbox with lower trust.

AppDomains are a fundamental part of the .Net Framework. You can load another copy of the .Net program into a second AppDomain. AppDomains actually provide a lot more control over the security. You can restrict and enable network connectivity for example.

The only downside with this is that the process will still be admin-trusted overall. So, ideally, you would have two completely separate .exe programs. One is the one with the code to do the trusted work, and the other has the low-trust settings built into the manifest and signed by the vendor. You would have the added benefit of having a low-trust program that can be run by low-trusted users.

Note: In DotNetCore there is no AppDomain - they have a different approach where "assemblies" can be loaded and unloaded, but you need to be careful not to reference any objects from within a referenced assembly.

Comment: The same kind of workaround might work for Threads, but that depends on the async model being used, I'm not sure if you can mark the ThreadPool threads to use a different identity. AppDomains are certainly easier, and more workabout workaround solution

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration file, you could have the installer create a config subdirectory and open the permissions up on it so that the service has write permissions to it.   For the update portions, it's not a best practice to have an MSI install a bunch of files and then have the application self update itself out of band.  It's a separation of concerns violation from an installer perspective.  If you must do this I suggest installing the newer bits in it's own folder (also granted permissions by the installer)  and use sometime of runtime  IoC/DI  to use those files instead of the ones installed by the installer.

There are also ways to author an MSI so that it can be upgraded without requiring admin rights.

Otherwise two services are possible also.  One to manage the upgrade/configuration story and another to do the business processing.   Some third party frameworks are out there for this type of situation.  I know how to write these but have chosen not to employ them in my consulting out of security/liability concerns.

Recently a Chinese company was in the news for a driver/service (as I recall) that could be exploited to take over the machine.  I don't ever want to be the one to facilitate that happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm looking for an answer of whether it's possible, not whether it should be done. The decision of whether it should be done should be applied on a case by case basis. In my situation, I'm updating the hosts file.

Comment: I'd say feel free to ignore my 23 years of experience but you stole my two services approach and posted it in your own answer.

Comment: `Of course, as a console application, a second process can be spawned without administrator rights, but for a service, I might need to have two services.` this was in the OP before your answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55446594/revisions